# What is the time-limit for whatsapp message to be secure in their server while offline?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I know whenever I delete my Whatsapp app on my Android device, I get all the messages till I install again......

What is the time-limit for this?

What if I reinstall Whatsapp after a year? Will I get all messages for being-offline-time?

Thanks!

Comment: the messages will be downloaded instantly and  stored in your phone's internal memory and not in the whatsapp server so unless you dont factory reset or delete whatsapp data in your phone it will be available to you always..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to my knowledge the message will be there for 30 days.Please refer the article attached in the [link](http://www.yourdailymac.net/2012/02/whatsapp-storing-messages-of-users-up-to-30-days/).